# Entity Framework - The property cannot be configured as a navigation property

Tags: entity-framework

I'm defining two entities like the following, but a strange behavior is occurring:

```
[Table("ClientTypes", Schema="dbo")]
public ClientType {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("Clients", Schema="dbo")]
public Client {

    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClientTypeId")]
    public int ClientTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ClientType ClientType { get; set; }
}
```

I'm getting the `ClientTypeId` property filled with some value, but the `ClientType` object is filled with nothing. Can someone help me with this?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ForeignKey` attribute as you have it is on the wrong property.

> The annotation may be placed on the foreign key property and specify the associated navigation property name, or placed on a navigation property and specify the associated foreign key name.

<sub>- [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)</sub>

`[ForeignKey("ClientTypeId")]` should decorate `public virtual ClientType ClientType` instead,

or change it to `[ForeignKey("ClientType")]` and leave it where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you eagerly loading the value?

```
var clients = context.Clients.Include("ClientType").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

When selecting the Client you have to `Include` the client type

```
Client cli = (from c in db Clients.Include("ClientType")//or the name of the property
              select c).First();
```

This translates to a left join and selects the data for Client and ClientType.
If you skip the `Include` the EF will select the data only for the client when execute the statement. 
As Mike said if the context is still available the property will be lazy loaded when you access it.

Comment: Your last sentence isn't necessarily true. The ClientType is virtual on Client, so if the context is still available it will lazy load ClientType.